# Control-M Calendar -- is it possible to set a job run on calendar where days are not selected

Tags: calendar, selected, control-m

With Control-M, I need to set JobA run on normal days, JobB run on holiday.

What I did:

1. Create 2 calendars: CALENDAR_NORMAL    CALENDAR_HOLIDAY
2. JobA run on CALENDAR_NORMAL
3. JobB run on CALENDAR_HOLIDAY

Above setting works fine. But need to maintain 2 calendars which days are mutual-excluded. Is it possible to:

1. Create 1 calendar: CALENDAR_HOLIDAY
2. JobA run on days which are not selected in CALENDAR_HOLIDAY
3. JobB run on CALENDAR_HOLIDAY

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two individual standard calendars into a periodic calendar.
You can define period A to be normal days and period B to be holidays.

Here is an example where 25/12 is marked as a holiday:

[image: CALENDAR]

You then simply configure jobA to run during period A and jobB to run during period B.

JobA:

[image: JOBA]

JobB:

[image: JOBB]

Resulting Schedule:

[image: SCHEDULE]

Comment: Thanks the comment.
I actually go with a 'exclude this calendar' way. It's an option between 'Calendar' and 'Period'. Will try with your solution later.
There's a minor problem with 'exclude' way. When save the setup, the scheduler work as expected and from exported xml we can see the code with a ~ before calendar, which I believe it denotes for 'not'. However when you open job property, can not find 'exclude' even I did it before. this will mislead people who check setup from Job Property UI.